# v-for object in objects doesn't rerender when this.objects changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I have a `mounted()` with `reloadComparisons()` and this tag:

```
<li v-for="comparison in comparisons">C: [[ comparison.area ]]</li>
```

The problem is that this is rendered only when `comparisons` is defined in `data`, when I load new array, it doesn't work.

I tried already `Vue.set(this.comparisons,comparisons)` but it doesn't react neither.

Do you know what to do?

**EDIT**

```
var app = new Vue({
            delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
            el: '#vue',
            data: {
                comparisons: [{'area': 'xxxx'}],
            },
            mounted() {
                this.reloadComparisons()
            },
            methods: {
                reloadComparisons: function () {
                    console.log('reloadComparisons');
                    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/alex/api/pricemap_comparisons/").then(function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        if (response.status === 200) {
                            this.comparisons = response.data.results;
                            Vue.set(this.comparisons, response.data.results);
                            console.log(this.comparisons);
                        }
                    }).catch()
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: can you provide use the code ?

Comment: @Ifaruki yes, I've added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you lost your `this` context. Try the following:

```
reloadComparisons: function () {
    console.log('reloadComparisons');
    const that = this;                   
  axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/alex/api/pricemap_comparisons/")
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 200) {
           that.comparisons = response.data.results;
           Vue.set(that.comparisons, response.data.results);
           console.log(that.comparisons);
        }
     )}.catch()
   }
```

Or even better: If you use webpack (or other modern buildchains with babel) use arrow functions so your context keeps right

Comment: Yes, it was the problem, I solved it other way, I just use `app.comparisons = ` instead `this.comparisons = `, thanks